# Confused by JQuery Docs about .submit() event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw a example describe in Official Document https://api.jquery.com/submit/

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Now when the form is submitted, the message is alerted. This happens prior to the actual submission, so we can cancel the submit action by calling .preventDefault() on the event object or by returning false from our handler. We can trigger the event manually when another element is clicked:"

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});
```

After this code executes, clicks on Trigger the handler will also display the message. In addition, the default submit action on the form will be fired, so the form will be submitted.

====I am not sure my understanding is correct?===

it says, the submit event can be prevent by call .preventDefault().

However the form can be summit by call .submit() manually.

as i tried, the .submit() event is not submit the form.

Comment: Please read documentation more carefully

Comment: If default action is prevented by setting `event.preventDefault()` inside jQuery submit handler, then `$( "#form" ).submit();` won't submit the FORM but trigger jQuery submit bound handler. To submit FORM, you need then to call `submit()` DOM native method, e.g `$('#form')[0].submit();`  or unbind previously preventing submit handler: `$('#form').off('submit').submit();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is wrong:

> In addition, the default submit action on the form will be fired

And when you call event.preventDefault() then the form will not be submitted until you submit the form like below:

```
$('form')[0].submit();//write this code inside your function.
```

Comment: `the form will not be submitted until you submit the form like below` Then i guess you meant e.g: `$('form')[0].submit();`

Comment: do you mean, once i have .preventDefault() in submit handler, is there no way i can submit my form by call submit() ?

Comment: You should call form submit as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: @EnXie You should read more carefully comments and btw jQuery DOC ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#target").submit(function() {
    (...)
});
```

Sets your custom submit handler to be called upon form submission.

```
$("#target").submit();
```

Calls the form submit. This means that when you have your custom submit handler set, it is called.